# Javascript - How to have the name of the players with queryselector?

Tags: javascript, html, tic-tac-toe

I create a system to have the names of the players
how get the 2 values of the names

I create 2 input text and I want take the 2 values to show the name's players but I can not:

**HTML:**

```
<section id="first_section" class="first_section">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nom du premier joueur" style="color: blue; font-size: 120px;" size="500" id="firsttext"><br>
  <button type="button" id="first_button">Suiva`enter code here`nt ></button>
</section>

<section id="second_section" class="second_section">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nom du deuxième joueur" style="color: blue; font-size: 120px;" size="500" id="secondtext"><br>
  <button type="button" id="second_button">Suivant ></button>
</section>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var firsttext = [document.querySelector("#firsttext").element, document.querySelector("#secondtext").element];


if (!estValide(this))
  {
    afficheur.sendMessage("Case occupée ! <br />Joueur " + firsttext[tour] + " c'est toujours à vous !");

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shorter and cleaner way to do this is to use a single button to check and retrieve both the input values then assign the retrieved values to your `firsttext` array like this:

```js
/* JavaScript */

var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var firsttext = [];

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var player1 = document.getElementById("firsttext");
  var player2 = document.getElementById("secondtext");
  
  if (player1.value != "" && player2.value != "") {
    firsttext.push(player1.value);
    firsttext.push(player2.value);
    alert(firsttext);
    return firsttext;
  } else {
   alert("Enter players' names");
  }
 
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<section id="first_section" class="first_section">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nom du premier joueur" id="firsttext"><br>
</section>
<p></p>
<section id="second_section" class="second_section">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nom du deuxième joueur" id="secondtext"><br>

</section>

<section id="button">
    <button type="button" id="second_button">Suivant ></button>
</section>
```

Comment: @Spyynox what error are you getting with the second? I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
let firstTextEl = document.querySelector("#firsttext"),
    firstValue = firstTextEl.value,
    secondTextEl = document.querySelector("#secondtext"),
    secondValue = secondTextEl.value;
```

The querySelector gets the input itself, then you simply use .value() to get the value of that input element.

Comment: He scores undefined... 
                    let firstTextEl = document.querySelector("#firsttext"),
                    firstValue = firstTextEl.value,
                    secondTextEl = document.querySelector("#secondtext"),
                    secondValue = secondTextEl.value;   
                afficheur.sendMessage("Le jeu peut commencer ! <br />  " + firstValue[tour] + " c'est votre tour.");